# R: Surrogate for selecting rownames on a tibble column

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tibble, r-rownames

The question is how to use a column on a tibble to select the whole row. The code below shows what I normally do using basic R functions to index rows I want to eliminate form the data frame dataMet. I was wondering if I can use tidyverse functions on a tibble to get the same results.
Thanks!

```
outL <- c("S11", "S156", "S302")
index <- match(outL, rownames(dataMet))

# Print Outliers
outL
dataMet[index,]

# Remove Outliers
dataMet <- dataMet[-index,]
```

EDIT: to clarify, I want to conduct this operation without using rownames. Instead, I want to subset the data according to matches between a vector and a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More options

```r
library(dplyr)


mydata <- data.frame(col1 = letters[1:10],
           col2 = 1:10)

slice(mydata, c(1, 3, 5))
#>   col1 col2
#> 1    a    1
#> 2    c    3
#> 3    e    5

slice(mydata, c(-1, -3, -5))
#>   col1 col2
#> 1    b    2
#> 2    d    4
#> 3    f    6
#> 4    g    7
#> 5    h    8
#> 6    i    9
#> 7    j   10

mydata$rownumber <- 1:nrow(mydata)

mydata$crownumber <- as.character(1:nrow(mydata))
str(mydata)

#> 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ col1      : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#>  $ col2      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>  $ rownumber : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>  $ crownumber: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...

myvector <- c(1, 2, 5)
mycvector <- c("6", "4", "8")

mydata %>% filter(col2 %in% myvector)
#>   col1 col2 rownumber crownumber
#> 1    a    1         1          1
#> 2    b    2         2          2
#> 3    e    5         5          5

mydata %>% filter(col2 %in% mycvector)
#>   col1 col2 rownumber crownumber
#> 1    d    4         4          4
#> 2    f    6         6          6
#> 3    h    8         8          8
```

Comment: Thanks, the main problem I have is that the tibble format doesn't works well with row-names. I was wondering if I can have the information of row names into a tibble column and slice that. Something along the lines of  slice(mydata$col1, c('a', 'c', 'e')). Basically conduct the operation without using row names

Comment: I'm actually more confused now but I'll give you some more options...